# Prevent countdown reset on page load

Tags: javascript, countdown

I have a stock counter that works fine, but I would like to prevent the countdown from resetting when the page reloads.

```
<span class="qty" id="qty"></span>

<script>
    var qty = 57
    var qtyId = document.getElementById("qty");

    setQty(qty);

    function setQty(qty)
    {
        qtyId.innerHTML = qty;

        if (qty==0) return;

        var parts = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
        if (parts > qty) parts = qty;

        var msec =  Math.floor(((Math.random() * 15) + 15)*1000);

        qty -= parts;

        setTimeout(function() {
            setQty(qty);
        }, msec)
    }
</script>
```

I've tried this based on other scripts, but it doesn't stop the countdown from resetting on page reload.

```
    var qty = 57
    var qtyId = document.getElementById("qty");

    setQty(qty);
    
        var saved_countdown = localStorage.getItem('saved_countdown');

    if(saved_countdown == null) {
        // Set the time we're counting down to using the time allowed

        time = new_countdown;
        localStorage.setItem('saved_countdown', new_countdown);
    } else {
        time = saved_countdown;
    }

    function setQty(qty)
    {
        qtyId.innerHTML = qty;

        if (qty==0) return;

        var parts = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
        if (parts > qty) parts = qty;

        var msec =  Math.floor(((Math.random() * 15) + 15)*1000);

        qty -= parts;

        setTimeout(function() {
            setQty(qty);
        }, msec)
    }
```

Would anyone here be able to help me out? Thank you!

Comment: `new_countdown` is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version doesn't work because you're trying to assign a non-existing variable (`new_countdown`) to `time`. I've refactored your code and fixed the problem:

```html
<span class="qty" id="qty"></span>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>

<script>
    const setQty = (qty) => {
        qtySpan.innerHTML = qty;

        if (qty == 0) return;

        let parts = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
        if (parts > qty) parts = qty;

        const msec =  Math.floor(((Math.random() * 15) + 15) * 1000);
        qty -= parts;

        // Save the updated quantity in localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('saved_countdown', qty);

        setTimeout(() => setQty(qty), msec);
    }

    // Get the saved countdown value from localStorage, or use default value of 57 if not found
    const defaultQty = localStorage.getItem('saved_countdown') ?? 57;
    
    const qtySpan = document.getElementById('qty');
    const resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset');

    // Add a click event listener to the reset button
    resetBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // Remove the saved countdown value from localStorage and refresh the page
        localStorage.removeItem('saved_countdown');
        location.reload();
    });

    // Set the initial value of the quantity
    setQty(defaultQty);
</script>
```

Comment: Please note that this version will apply the qty calculation logic on each page refresh, i.e. it's possible to circumvent the timeout by refreshing the page multiple times. Please let me know if you would like to preserve the timeout after refreshing and I will edit the code if needed.

Comment: I removed the reset button but, it was exactly what I needed, thanks a lot!

Now, I just came across another problem, I need to show the counter down in more than one place on the same page and with different "speed", but I couldn't do that… It only appears 1 time on the page… haha